# Repeat no-effort answers, Looks OK or Delete?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality, review

As an example, which does happen every now and again, this answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/72384/14897

It is a one-liner that was posted four hours after two back-to-back answers, and doesn't add anything new.

As of writing this, the [review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/47955) is a tie 2:2. And the score is +4/-4.

What are your thoughts on how such answers should be reviewed?

Comment: The score is 1.......

Comment: @Abdullah: +6/-5 since :D

Answer (score 8):

I checked MSE, and found two posts related to this issue, from which:

> If someone leaves an identical answer on an old question (for some arbitrary definition of "old"), cast a deletion vote or flag with a custom explanation, and ask for deletion. ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171222/392799))

and

> Every additional answer adds noise.
>
> The presence of many similar answers essentially all saying the same thing makes it harder for later answers that may contribute something new to be spotted. ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203384/392799))

***Given those points:***

<kbd>Looks OK</kbd> is valid on the technicality of considering the post *in isolation,* but it should not be considered in isolation, as such answers do add noise and are no-effort. But how would the reviewer know if they didn't check the whole post?

Update: the new review UI now allows viewing the other answers from the same review window.

Therefore, **if** noted in a comment, as Federico ♦ has done for the given example, and as I and others have done in the past, IMO the review should be <kbd>Delete</kbd> / <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd>. (Note: such posts go into the queue *after* one or more low-quality flags.)

Answer (score 5):

Delete.

I agree that answers can't be considered in isolation.

The only answer on a question, if not incorrect and not useless, should generally be kept upon meeting minimal criteria. In contrast, on a "hot question", many answers that would in isolation not even raise a flag, may well contain nothing that hasn't been covered already.

SE is not a platform for self-expression. Self-expression is not to be specifically restricted or removed, but it should never be the only value contributed by a question or answer post. Agreement with other posts is properly expressed by upvoting.

I'd consider this to apply retroactively to a limited extent, i.e. a **very** lazy but technically correct answer, that normally deserves removal, still deserves it even if it was the first, but has been superseded by high-quality answers.

Comment: RE retroactive deletion: What may come across as laziness *(as the first to answer)* may just be best effort. Here, simply upvoting the better answer is enough IMO. That being said, generally I agree to the principle **if** the older answer did not answer the question.

Comment: @ymb1 I'm referring to no-effort one-liners such as "Yes" or "It's not profitable".